# Scheduling hadoop job once in a week for past two years

Tags: rhel

I am new to Linux Shell scripting.Currently I am working on a requirement where the project has 2 years of data residing in each day partitions.Each day partition has 200 files that needs to merged into one single file.

I have developed a code which would input a variable leveraging the current date. below is the snippet.I am looking for a way to use loop without any manual intervention and it should be running once a week.

```
daysToDeduct=<number>
day1=$((daysToDeduct-1))
day2=$((daysToDeduct-2))
day3=$((daysToDeduct-3))
day4=$((daysToDeduct-4))
day5=$((daysToDeduct-5))
day6=$((daysToDeduct-6))
day7=$((daysToDeduct-7))

DAY1=`date --date="$day1 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
DAY2=`date --date="$day2 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
DAY3=`date --date="$day3 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
DAY4=`date --date="$day4 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
DAY5=`date --date="$day5 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
DAY6=`date --date="$day6 days ago" +%Y%m%d`
DAY7=`date --date="$day7 days ago" +%Y%m%d`


hadoop fs -getmerge  /apps/..../$DAY1  /.../$DAY1
.

...
hadoop fs -getmerge  /apps/..../$DAY7  /.../$DAY7
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will help you.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do 
    echo $i: $(date --date="$i days ago" +%Y%m%d)
done
```

This snippet prints :

```
1: 20191006
2: 20191005
3: 20191004
4: 20191003
5: 20191002
6: 20191001
7: 20190930
8: 20190929
9: 20190928
10: 20190927
```

1. You use sec to loop from 1 to 200
2. You define it as a date (which i simply printed)

Hope that will help :)

Thanks to @Stephen Kitt for the improvements !

Comment: Days aren’t always 24 hours long. You should use `date --date="-${TODAY}days"` instead, or the same pattern as in the question.

Comment: This is a good suggestion indeed. I'm applying this solution for the script !